# Android DatePreference Default Value Not Set?

Tags: android, default-value, preference

How To Set DatePreference Default Value From Java Side.

I Want Set to Date "Now"

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found Solution This

dpDate.setDate(tools.NowDate());

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking about, as I don't know what a "DatePreference" is, and neither does Google.

With Java and Android, you have a few options for representing and working with date/time data.  To represent "Now":

- You could use [java.util.Date](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).  The no argument constructor creates a Date object that "represents the time at which it was allocated".
- You could use [java.util.Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).  Calendar.getInstance() returns "a Calendar subclass instance set to the current date and time in the default Timezone".
- You could use a primitive long value.  [System](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).currentTimeMillis() returns "the current time in milliseconds".
- You could use [android.text.format.Time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html), which is "a faster replacement for" Calendar.  After constructing or otherwise obtaining a Time object, call setToNow() to set the time "to the current time".
- Before Android, I know a lot of folks preferred to use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net) when working with date/time data in Java.  With Joda-Time, you could create a new [joda.time.DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) instance with the no argument constructor, which would then represent "the current system millisecond time using ISOChronology in the default time zone".

I also recommend reviewing the [android.os.SystemClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html) documentation, when working with date/time events in Android.

Comment: you dont understand me. Date Preference is Like ListPreference.
i want to set default value dete preference

Comment: I still don't understand.  What have you tried to do?  What does that code look like?  What did you expect the code to do?  What did it appear to do instead?